# how can I log errors in php 5.2?

Tags: php, http, iis, logging, error-logging

This tells me the location of some log files in windows\temp:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

[image]

However when I open that file, I get:

```
[06-Feb-2013 11:01:34] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
[06-Feb-2013 11:04:37] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
[06-Feb-2013 11:04:37] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

THat is the entire contents of the file,. Please note that we've been using this site for several months with several dozen users.

I am unable to find the log files,.

We are running IIS 8, and I've also been trying to use that to find http errors, and cannot.

Where are the error logs for php and iis?

Comment: Does your application override error handling?

Comment: off topic, but it's worth pointing out that PHP 5.2 is obsolete -- PHP 5.3 has been available for nearly four years now, and 5.2 was declared end-of-life more than two years ago, with no more support or security fixes. It's way past time to upgrade. In fact, with 5.5 coming soon, the end might be in sight for 5.3. Be careful not to let yourself get too far behind, because the longer you leave it, it gets harder and harder to upgrade.

Comment: @Spudley totally agree but unfortunately im not the decision maker

Comment: @datasage sorry i just saw your message. i dont think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in `php.ini` contains `error_log=On` then it will be store a log file.

You need add a module for loading, this errors show because in `php.ini` is active module but you should disable or comment if you not in use.

Windows store in system default log file, so find `php.ini` file and search for `error_log`.

Or find how is stored on system environment maybe is there, find by date:

[image]

Or search on `C:\inetpub\temp\php-errors.log` or type php*.log in search.

There can be stored by default in `Log file directory: C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles` too.

Can you check for this and set to development?

[image]

As you can see, view error.log file.

And please see OFFICIAL PHP.NET documentation for setting IIS7 and later: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php Make sure that all parameters are done.

Comment: thanks marin, but i already had the path set

Comment: Can you try using search file log and open a PHP file where is error occurred and then sort by date to pick a log? On IIS7 when I never find a log I have found by sorting a date in search of files...

Comment: thank you i am searching right now for php files on C

Comment: i searched the entire system and could not fin dit

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini file and make sure **log_errors = On**, also make sure **error_log = syslog** (syslog is Event Viewer on Windows), open Event Viewer and look for errors.

Comment: he's asking where the logs are. This has nothing to do with the question. Please remove it

Comment: after specifying this ; Log errors to specified file.
error_log = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\error_log.txt"
 do i need to restart iis?

Comment: Yes, changing php.ini requires service restart (at least in apache).

Comment: @Eldar which service?

Comment: @eldar i know that when i turned the errors ON to be displayed right away to the user, it DID NOT require anything to be restarted

Comment: I am used to Apache... :)